# Java printing thread gets stuck : WHY?

Tags: java, multithreading, printing, rhel, cups

In my Java 8 application (RHEL 6.x, Wildfly 10.1.0.Final) the first time a user prints a document, application gets stuck while getting the list of printers from the system.

Here is the stacktrace of the blocking thread :

```
"Thread-211" #799 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fca543a6800 nid=0x10755 runnable [0x00007fca02820000]

   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.print.CUPSPrinter.canConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.print.CUPSPrinter.isCupsRunning(CUPSPrinter.java:444)
    at sun.print.UnixPrintServiceLookup.getDefaultPrintService(UnixPrintServiceLookup.java:650)
    - locked <0x00000006d2c7fff8> (a sun.print.UnixPrintServiceLookup)
    at sun.print.UnixPrintServiceLookup.refreshServices(UnixPrintServiceLookup.java:277)
    - locked <0x00000006d2c7fff8> (a sun.print.UnixPrintServiceLookup)
    at sun.print.UnixPrintServiceLookup$PrinterChangeListener.run(UnixPrintServiceLookup.java:947)
```

Other users trying to print documents and relatives threads are blocked by this one.

I looked at the source code of `CUPSPrinter.canConnect()` (native code) and at this point we try to connect to the cups server :

```
/*
 * Checks if connection can be made to the server.
 *
 */
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL
Java_sun_print_CUPSPrinter_canConnect(JNIEnv *env,
                                      jobject printObj,
                                      jstring server,
                                      jint port)
{
    const char *serverName;
    serverName = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, server, NULL);
    if (serverName != NULL) {
        http_t *http = j2d_httpConnect(serverName, (int)port);
        (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, server, serverName);
        if (http != NULL) {
            j2d_httpClose(http);
            return JNI_TRUE;
        }
    }
    return JNI_FALSE;
}
```

In my case CUPS is on the same host listening on port 631.
I checked the logs & everything seems to be fine.

I also checked active connections for cups with netstat :

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      76107/cupsd         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45652             127.0.0.1:631               TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 :::631                      :::*                        LISTEN      76107/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 ::1:35982                   ::1:631                     TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 ::1:35981                   ::1:631                     TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 ::1:35978                   ::1:631                     TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 ::1:35979                   ::1:631                     TIME_WAIT   -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631                 0.0.0.0:*                               76107/cupsd
```

**Important notes :**

- If I restart Cups service, thread is not deblocked. It seems to live endessly until application restarts.
- I found a bug similar to this on Open JDK : https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6290446  But the workaround of setting `-Dsun.java2d.print.polling=false` does not work for me (the property seems to be cleared at some point for an obscure reason, so `PrinterChangeListener` gets instantiated and though polling is not desactivated).
- I can't reproduce the problem with a test application (clone of production) on the same server

Please HELP !!

Answer (score -2):

-Djava.awt.printerjob=sun.print.PSPrinterJob